Implementing arc-length parameterization and adaptive subdivision for Bézier curves
I'm attempting to determine multiple aspects about a Bézier curve programmatically. I want to be able to find the arc length of the curve, points positioned along the curve with higher density at areas with a higher measure of curvature, and points positioned equidistant from each other. Currently, I store the list of controls in an array and use de Casteljau's recursive algorithm to find points and derivatives. A snippet of my implementation in luau follows:
function Bezier:Hodograph(t: number): Curve<Bezier> -- A single step in the Casteljau algorithm. Yields a curve 1 degree lower than itself.
    local hodograph = Bezier.new()
    for i = 1, #self.Controls - 1 do
        hodograph.Controls[i] = self.Controls[i]:Lerp(self.Controls[i+1], t)
    end
    return hodograph
end

function Bezier:Casteljau(t: number, derivative: number?): Curve<Bezier> -- Reduces control points and returns a new curve containing the control points.
    derivative = derivative or 0
    
    if #self.Controls <= derivative+1 then
        return self
    end
    
    return self:Hodograph(t):Casteljau(t, derivative)
end

function Bezier:Split(t: number): (Curve<Bezier>, Curve<Bezier>) -- Cuts the curve at point `t` and returns the slices in a tuple, left before right.
    local left = Bezier.new()
    local right = Bezier.new()
    
    local hodograph = self
    for i = 1, #self.Controls do
        left.Controls[i] = hodograph.Controls[1]
        right.Controls[(#self.Controls) - (i-1)] = hodograph.Controls[#hodograph.Controls]
        hodograph = hodograph:Hodograph(t)
    end
    
    return left, right
end

function Bezier:GetPoint(t: number): Vector3
    return self:Casteljau(t).Controls[1]
end

function Bezier:GetTangent(t: number): Vector3 -- Gets the 1st derivative, or rate of change (tangent) of point t.
    local controls: {Vector3} = self:Casteljau(t, 1).Controls
    
    if #controls < 2 then
        return Vector3.zero -- Not enough control points to calculate first derivative (tangent).
    end
    
    return ((controls[2] - controls[1]) * (#self.Controls - 1))
end

function Bezier:GetAcceleration(t: number): Vector3 -- Gets the 2nd derivative, or rate of change in tangent (acceleration) of point t.
    local controls: {Vector3} = self:Casteljau(t, 2).Controls
    
    if #controls < 3 then
        return Vector3.zero -- Not enough control points to calculate second derivative (acceleration).
    end
    
    return ((controls[3] - 2 * controls[2] + controls[1]) * (#self.Controls - 1) * (#self.Controls - 2))
end

function Bezier:GetCurvature(t: number): number
    local secondDerivative = self:Casteljau(t, 2)
    local tangent: Vector3 = secondDerivative:GetTangent(t)
    local acceleration: Vector3 = secondDerivative:GetAcceleration(t)
    
    local cross = tangent:Cross(acceleration)
    
    local speed = tangent.Magnitude^3
    if speed == 0 then
        return 0
    else
        return cross.Magnitude / speed
    end
end

As you can see, I've already created methods for the first and second derivatives (tangent and acceleration), as well as a method to find curvature. I need some sort of method that can parameterize the arc length of the curve adaptively, emphasizing curves and ensuring that areas with little curvature don't get too much density.
I've tried iterating through the curve with different time values, changing the size of steps based on curvature, subdividing until distance between points reached a certain epsilon, yet none of my methods are very "scientific." They all require some sort of value passed into the function or a rough approximation on what do to next. I need a function that's reliable and returns a parameterization of quality in minimal time while only using concrete aspects of the curve itself, no arbitrary weighting or error checking.

You can't, there is no solution for the arc length for cubic and higher Bezier curves. So approximations involving either numerical solutions (e.g. constructing a distance based lookup tables and interpolating for intermediary values) or (piecewise) functional approximation are the best you're going to get.

It's possible to make smooth polyline, just set the max angular difference and find the next nearest t to fit this angle (with tolerance).

@darkfrei how would I actually ensure that the next time value is on the same curve segment without sampling curvature for parts of the curve that I won't use?

I think your determination to find a solution that's "scientific" is keeping you from finding/settling on a practical solution. Start with a hardcoded subdivision; if needed, add adaptive midpoint subdivision (that is, recursively add samples halfway between samples, continuing to recurse if the discontinuity in derivative at the added sample is above a limit); if still needed (and it's probably not), use gradient descent to refine the solution, moving the parameters of your samples to maximize the second derivative and coalescing sample points when they run into each other.
There are more complicated approaches, but honestly it seems unlikely that their effect on the quality of your application would be worth the difficulty of implementation.
